# How can I change the remote/target repository URL on Windows?

Tags: windows, git, github

I created a local GIT repository on Windows. Let's call it AAA. I staged, committed, and pushed the contents to GitHub. `git@github.com:username/AAA.git`

I realized I made a mistake with the name.

On GitHub, I renamed it to `git@github.com:username/BBB.git`

Now, on my Windows machine, I need to change `git@github.com:username/AAA.git` to `git@github.com:username/BBB.git` because the settings are still trying to "push" to `git@github.com:username/AAA.git` but I need to push to `git@github.com:username/BBB.git` now.

How could I do that?

Answer (score 132, accepted):

The easiest way to tweak this in my opinion (imho) is to edit the .git/config file in your repository. Look for the entry you messed up and just tweak the URL.

On my machine in a repo I regularly use it looks like this:

```
KidA% cat .git/config 
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    ignorecase = true
    autocflg = true
[remote "origin"]
    url = ssh://localhost:8888/opt/local/var/git/project.git
    #url = ssh://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:80/opt/local/var/git/project.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

The line you see commented out is an alternative address for the repository that I sometimes switch to simply by changing which line is commented out.

This is the file that is getting manipulated under-the-hood when you run something like `git remote rm` or `git remote add` but in this case since its only a typo you made it might make sense to correct it this way.

Answer (score 274):

```
git remote set-url origin <URL>
```

Comment: This seems to work fine. If you're copying an existing repo to a new one, however, you'll need to follow this up with git push origin master.

Comment: I have added a similar solution at the bootom. http://stackoverflow.com/a/15784886/1177575

Comment: I like this way, it fits conveniently in a workflow where i copy a .git/config from another repo when I initialize a new one.

Answer (score 62):

One more way to do this is:

```
git config remote.origin.url https://github.com/abc/abc.git
```

To see the existing URL just do:

```
git config remote.origin.url
```

Answer (score 25):

Take a look in .git/config and make the changes you need.

Alternatively you could use

```
git remote rm [name of the url you sets on adding]
```

and

```
git remote add [name] [URL]
```

Or just

```
git remote set-url [URL]
```

Before you do anything wrong, double check with

```
git help remote
```